# Odd time riff suggestion

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, recording

I'm trying to record this riff as accurately as possible, but when playing it I have a few problems:

1. When hitting a power chord, I sometimes hit it twice (extra hit on the unnecessary up stroke).
2. Sometimes I do the gallop instead of 16th note chug.
3. 6th string chugs start to sound fuzzy after playing this riff on second cycle (as you can see, there's a repeat indicated).

I've practiced it but still pretty hard for me to play. What would be your suggestions about pick positioning (90º with the strings – (nearly) perfectly perpendicular or other angles) and also maybe you can give suggestions about replacing the striking pattern. Thanks!

[image: riff]

Comment: Unless this is quite fast I suspect I'd use only downstrokes with the pick angled so it's under my hand, which would be quite flat and damping the strings.

Answer (score 3):

The direction of the pick is shown as the best way to play it. It means your hand goes up and down in a regular way, which is good. If you change that, it's asking for trouble. Play everything muted, and, as Todd says (as most others would agree with) play it all painfully slowly, giving time for muscle memory to work. If you play it faster and it's still wrong - it's still too quick! But the direction of pick needs following.